# RegEx ignore word preciding a character set

Tags: node.js, regex

I have the following string that I am trying to match with RegEx:

```
286,879 in Home & Kitchen (See Top 100 in Home & Kitchen)  
339 in Cardboard Cutouts    
2,945 in Jigsaws (Toys & Games)
```

This is my code/regex:

```
            const matches = text.matchAll(/(?<!Top )([\d,|]+) in[\s\n ]([\w&'\s]+)/g);
            for(const match of matches){
                const rank = parseInt(match[1].replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
                const category = match[2].trim()
                console.log(`${category} = ${rank}`)
            }
```

However, the the only parts it should match on are: `286,879 in Home & Kitchen`, `339 in Cardboard Cutouts`, `2,945 in Jigsaws (Toys & Games)`

The expected output should be:

```
Home & Kitchen = 286879

Cardboard Cutouts = 339

Jigsaws = 2945
```

How can I adjust the regex to ignore the `100 in Home & Kitchen` string

Thanks

Comment: Note that RegEx can't match balanced parentheses, so as soon as you have a string like `X in Y (See (!) yay)` it will fall apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups:

```
(?<!Top\s+)\b(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+in\s+([^()\n]*[^\s()])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!Top\s+)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `Top` followed by 1+ whitespace chars directly to the left of the current position.
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture *group 1*,  match 1+ digits with an optional `,` and 1+ digits
- `\s+in\s+` Match `in` between 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture *group 2*

  - `[^()\n]*[^\s()]` Match optional chars other than a newline and `(` `)`
- `)` Close *group 2*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tzI7N/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<!Top\s+)\b(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+in\s+([^()\n]*[^\s()])/;

[
  "const str = `286,879 in Home & Kitchen (See Top 100 in Home & Kitchen)",
  "339 in Cardboard Cutouts",
  "2,945 in Jigsaws (Toys & Games)`;"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`${m[2]} = ${m[1].replace(",", "")}`)
  }
})
```

Note that using `\s` could also match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exclude the things in the parentheses, you could try something like this:

```
/^([\d,|]+) in[\s\n ]([\w&'\s]+)(\s*\(.*\)\s*)?$/gm
```

And ignore the third capture group

Comment: Thanks, this nearly works. I notice that Match 2, Group 2 is returning the `2` from `2,945 in Jigsaws (Toys & Games)`

Comment: @Sam sorry, i forgot to add the anchors. I changed the regex to support multiline strings and removed the lookbehind at the start, since it is not needed (at least in those cases)

Answer (score 0):

###### [regex](https://regex101.com/r/nuBVMv/1) Groups:

1. `result` - one record from input (row)
2. `data` - numbers (including `,`)
3. `cat` - category name
4. `extra` - to be ignored

###### JS

- replace `result` with re-ordered `cat` (`$3`), `=` and `data` (`$2`)
- replace `,` with `empty`

```
const regex = /(?<result>(?<data>^[\d|,]+)(?: in )(?<cat>.+?)(?<extra>\s+(?:\(.+?\)?)?))$/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(?<result>(?<data>^[\\d|,]+)(?: in )(?<cat>.+?)(?<extra>\\s+(?:\\(.+?\\)?)?))$', 'gm')

const str = `286,879 in Home & Kitchen (See Top 100 in Home & Kitchen)  
339 in Cardboard Cutouts    
2,945 in Jigsaws (Toys & Games)`;
const subst = `$3 = $2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst).replace(',', '');

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```